# How do I interact with elements in d3.js v5 alongside zoom events

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement zoom in an existing javascript using d3.js v5.

Before adding zoom I used

```
svg.on('mouseup', function(){ 
  if(d3.event.target.hasAttribute('is-handle'){
    //do something
  }
});
```

to check if the target had a specific attribute.

This worked fine as, an example, seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/wLxuto54/

I want to be able to handle "mouseUp" when there is no change in zoom.
I have done this by checking if the mouse is moved between "zoomstart" and "zoomend".

But when zoom is implemented, I get an error in console saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: d3.event.target.hasAttribute is not a function
```

Full example code:

```
const width = 800,
      height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr('height', height)
            .attr('width', width)
            .call(d3.zoom()
                 .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
                 .on("start", zoomstart)
                 .on("end", zoomend)
                 .on("zoom", zoomed));

var g = svg.append("g");

var mousePos = null;

function zoomstart(){
  mousePos = d3.mouse(this);
}

function zoomend(){
  var m = d3.mouse(this);
  if (mousePos[0] ===  m[0] && mousePos[1] === m[1]){
    mouseUp();
  }
}       

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

function mouseUp(){
   if(d3.event.target.hasAttribute('is-handle')){
    console.log("IS HANDLE");
   }else{
  g.append('circle')
       .attr('cx', d3.mouse(this)[0])
       .attr('cy', d3.mouse(this)[1])
       .attr('r', 5)
       .attr('fill', 'yellow')
       .attr('stroke', '#000')
       .attr('is-handle', 'true')
       .style({cursor: 'pointer'});
   }
}
```

Or in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3f214eyt/

How can I fix this while still being able to interact with targeted objects on the "mouseUp" event?